# SQL injection via SQLmap - how does the UNION ALL Injection work?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

This is the payload that SQL map claims to be injectable:

```
user=-5305' UNION ALL SELECT
  NULL,CONCAT(0x716b6b7071,0x4f5577454f76734a4a567875585a6f6b544b6414f584b466d4f7968416e4c737a534c5158726478,0x717a6a6b71)-- QGHl&pass=a
```

How does it work in detail?

I mean the part with all those hex values...

Answer (score 3):

That are simply strings [encoded in hex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html).

This particular query does nothing harmful, but adding to the site's output the signal: "I'm up, and the site is injectable."

Comment: So from now one we know that this site is vulnerable to UNION query and we can use other techniques to retrieve data right? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Comment: Thanks :)so the "QGHl" doesnt mean anything to be clear

Comment: What encoding? ASCII? Unicode? What is the string supposed to be in this case?

Comment: @PeterMortensen honestly, I have no idea